# Настройка GIT

Tags: git, ssh, php

Ситуация такая: у меня есть репозиторий сайта на удаленном сервере. Мне надо, чтобы когда я заливаю изменения на сервер (push), обновлялась файлы сайта, т.е. сразу на нем показывались внесенные изменения.

Comment: Возможно, Вам понравиться [dploy.io](http://dploy.io/) - он бесплатный для одного репозитория.

Comment: @pirj, а вы пробовали взглянуть на дату вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете контроль версий и деплой в одно блюдо.
Изучите capistrano.
Есть deploy hook'и, но это не то, чего вы хотите и к чему стоит привыкать. Это не ftp.

Comment: Ну а что плохого в том, что сайт автоматом подтянет изменения из репозитория? Учитывая, что это тестовая версия.

Comment: Ничего плохого. Но сайт должен пуллить изменения в свою директорию. Это можно делать через hook.

Comment: @oldy: хотя бы в том, что вы могли удалить какой-то важный для приложения файл из репозитория, и забыть добавить его на сервере, при этом добавив у себя локально, например database.yml. Вы можете поправить это на своей тестовой версии, а потом та же история с сайтом, отказывающимся стартовать, случится и на продакшне.

Comment: Ну так добавлю я его опять же через репозиторий, откуда тестовый сайт его и обновит

Comment: Его не нужно добавлять в репозиторий, там пароли

Answer (score 1):

У меня подобное реализовано следующим образом.

Есть сервер с репозиториями, работает через gitolite. На нем же расположенны репозитории с dev версиями сайтов. По простенькому хуку post-receive на баше, выполняющему следующую команду:

```
/var/.../hook_git.php "$GL_REPO_BASE" "$GL_REPO"
```

запускается скриптик, который определяет нужный репозиторий и каталог с дев версией и жестко подтягивает изменения:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Итого имеем 4 репозитория на каждый проект:

1. Локальный.
2. Основной (в который пушим из локального).
3. Dev-репозиторий (в него автоматом подтягиваются изменения из основного по хукам).
4. Продакшн (в него ручками).

И все работает по феншую. Т.е. в non-bare репозиторий мы не пушим, а подтягиваем изменения из основного репозитория. Всегда имеем актуальную дев версию сайта.

Можно это все немного проапгрейдить. Например, комиты в dev ветку подтягивать на dev версию, master - на продакшн. Но я придерживаюсь мнения, что последнее лучше делать руками (по крайней мере для рядовых проектов, где не нужны адские системы деплоя).

Comment: Наконец оформил это более полно в виде статьи https://intsystem.org/server/gitolite-avtodeploj-dev-ili-kak-ya-rabotayu-s-git/ может кому будет интересно.